# Dividing the time into periods each 30 min

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, time, apache-spark-sql

I have Dataframe contains "time" column I want to add a new column contain period number after dividing the time into periods each 30 min
for example, 
The original Dataframe

```
l = [('A','2017-01-13 00:30:00'),('A','2017-01-13 00:00:01'),('E','2017-01-13 14:00:00'),('E','2017-01-13 12:08:15')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l,['test','time'])
df1 = df.select(df.test,df.time.cast('timestamp'))
df1.show()
+----+-------------------+
|test|               time|
+----+-------------------+
|   A|2017-01-13 00:30:00|
|   A|2017-01-13 00:00:01|
|   E|2017-01-13 14:00:00|
|   E|2017-01-13 12:08:15|
+----+-------------------+
```

The Desired Dataframe as follow:

```
+----+-------------------+------+
|test|               time|period|
+----+-------------------+------+
|   A|2017-01-13 00:30:00|     2|
|   A|2017-01-13 00:00:01|     1|
|   E|2017-01-13 14:00:00|    29|
|   E|2017-01-13 12:08:15|    25|
+----+-------------------+------+
```

Are there ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply utilize the `hour` and `minute` *inbuilt function*s to get your final result with `when` *inbuilt function* as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1.withColumn('period', (F.hour(df1['time'])*2)+1+(F.when(F.minute(df1['time']) >= 30, 1).otherwise(0))).show(truncate=False)
```

You should be getting

```
+----+---------------------+------+
|test|time                 |period|
+----+---------------------+------+
|A   |2017-01-13 00:30:00.0|2     |
|A   |2017-01-13 00:00:01.0|1     |
|E   |2017-01-13 14:00:00.0|29    |
|E   |2017-01-13 12:08:15.0|25    |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful